# Green () : and ;

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I shutdown a VS2010 project yesterday and everything was working well.  I opened it up today and one of the .cpp files has green formatting on the parenthesis, semi-colons, and colons (see attached photo).  Auto-complete is also not working.

I've deleted the .sdf file for the project, as that usually fixes the auto-complete issue.  This did not work.  Additionally, the broken .cpp file is still identified by VS2010 as a C/C++ file.  Google doesn't seem to turn up any folks with similar problems.

Has anyone encountered this issue?  How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying a few things, I finally figured it out.  I right clicked on the .cpp file that was acting weird, selected "Exclude from Project".  Then re-add the file back to the project and it seems to have fixed the problem.  Don't know why it happened in the first place, VS2010 must think it wasn't a .cpp file or something.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar thing before, though in VS2012. What I ended up doing was building the solution in release mode, then switching back to debug mode and re-built it again.